# Calculate $E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_{0}^{T_2}r_t\,dt} \frac{S\left(T_2\right)}{S\left(T_1\right)}\right]$

Tags: option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, martingale

Let $S\left(t\right)$ be a tradable financial security that doesn't generate cash flow (eg no dividend). $S\left(t\right)$ follows an unknown stochastic process.

We now have a financial derivative that pays $\frac{S\left(T_2\right)} {S\left(T_1\right)}$ at $t=T_2$, where $0<T_1<T_2$

Assume interest rate $r_t$ is not constant.

What's the present value of this financial derivative at $t=0$ ?

---

My attempt so far:

$V\left(0\right)=E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_{0}^{T_2}r_t\,dt} \frac{S\left(T_2\right)}{S\left(T_1\right)}\right]$

I believe my next step should be to get rid of the discount factor term. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Do you truly know nothing about $S(t)$?

Comment: @will Yes, you only need to know that $S(t)$ is a stochastic process. The model of $S(t)$ would not affect the answer.

Comment: Do you have any of its properties? Or is the question asking you to write down the integral representation of the expectation?

Comment: This question has something to do with converting risk neutral measure to forward measure. Then after some manipulation, the present value of the derivative should be a function of $r_t$. Present value of the derivative should end up not dependant on $S(t)$

Comment: That is only the case if we can make a bunch of assumptions on S. You need to give us all the assumptions you're allowed to make.

Comment: i disagree that the dynamics of the stochastic process do not change the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume [a Black-Scholes world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model) *except* the dynamics of the stock price, namely:

- No arbitrage opportunities.
- No dividend payments from the stock.
- Existence of a riskless asset yielding the risk free rate $-$ which here we assume non-constant, $(r_t)_{t \geq 0}$.
- Possibility to borrow and lend infinitely at the risk-free rate.
- Possibility to buy and sell infinitely the stock $-$ *even fractional amounts*.
- No transaction costs.

We also assume that the stock is tradable and that the derivative is attainable $-$ we basically assume we are in the standard pricing setting except for the stock price dynamics.

Then the price at time $t=0$, $V(0)$, of the derivative is given by:

$$ V(0) = P(0,T_1)$$

where $P(0,T_1)$ is the price of a riskless zero-coupon contracted at time $t=0$ and maturing at time $t=T_1$ $-$ which is effectively a function of the rate $r_t$ and is independent of $S(t)$.

**Financial proof**: the financial derivative you describe delivers a quantity $w$ of the stock at time $T_2$, where:

$$ w = \frac{1}{S(T_1)}$$

Thus $w$ will only be known at time $T_1$, when you will buy $w$ shares of the stock. But at that time, the value of such a position is trivially equal to $\$1$. Thus you only need to have $\$1$ at time $T_1$ to settle the trade at maturity $T_2$; no further transactions are needed. The value today of $\$1$ at $T_1$ is simply equal to the value of a zero-coupon bond contracted at $t=0$ and maturing at $T_1$. Hence:

$$ V(0) = P(0,T_1)$$

**Mathematical proof**: under the assumptions listed at the beginning, by the law of iterated expectations, adaptedness of the stock price with respect to a suitable filtration $(\mathcal{F})_{t \geq 0}$ and the martingality property of discounted stock prices under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$, we obtain:

$$ \begin{align}
V(0) & = E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_0^{T_2}r_t\,dt} \frac{S(T_2)}{S(T_1)}\right] 
\\[6pt]
& = E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_0^{T_2}r_t\,dt} \frac{S(T_2)}{S(T_1)}|\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\right]\right]
\\[6pt]
& = E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_0^{T_1}r_t\,dt}\frac{1}{S(T_1)}E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_{T_1}^{T_2}r_t\,dt} S(T_2)|\mathcal{F}_{T_1}\right]\right]
\\[6pt]
& = E^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[e^{-\int_0^{T_1}r_t\,dt}\frac{1}{S(T_1)}S(T_1)\right]
\\[9pt]
& = P(0,T_1)
\end{align} $$

Comment: This is only if you assume that $\mathrm{d}S_t = S_t r_t \mathrm{d}t + S_t \sigma \mathrm{d}W_t$. If you assume that, it should be obvious, since the discounting at the end will be $e^{\int_0^{T_2} r_t \mathrm{d}t}$, while while the expected value of $S(t)$ is $S_0 e^{\int_0^{t} r_\tau \mathrm{d}\tau}$ - i.e. the extra discounting from $T_1$ to $T_2$ will exactly match the expected performance, so you're left with the discounting up to the start of the period. This requires many assumptions about $S(t)$ though.

Comment: @will umm but the martingality property of the discounted stock price is independent of the posited stock price dynamics.

Comment: You're assuming $S(t)$ is matingale. I asked if we knew *nothing* about the process, and chengcj responded with "Yes, you only need to know that $S(t)$ is a stochastic process. The model of $S(t)$ would not affect the answer".

Comment: Additionally, stock prices do *not* grow at the risk free rate, they have dividends and repo rates which alter this. So you're assuming that the drift of the underlying exactly matches the rate $r$.

Comment: @will well I am assuming we are using risk-neutral pricing theory, which is independent of the stock price dynamics.

Comment: @will I am assuming no dividens as the OP did not mention them.

Comment: so mention this in the answer, as it makes a big difference. The answer they are seeking only works if you make these (large) assumptions - which they have (perhaps wrongly) stated that they cannot make.

Comment: @will I am basically assuming the Black-Scholes framework _except_ the dynamics of the stock price.

Comment: @will will make this more explicit.

Comment: (My impression was that the OP was implicitly assuming the usual hypothesis: no arbitrage, no transaction costs, no dividends, etc.)

Comment: i think that must be the case given the answer they're seeking - but they need to understand the difference it makes.

Comment: @will I am _not_ assuming $S(t)$ is a martingale by the way, but the discounted stock price, which is standard.

Comment: The fact that the expectation under Q exists (implicitly assumed by the question) means we know a lot about S.  We know that S is a martingale when denominated by a risk free asset; for one.  This is independent of the process which S follows.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof:   The contract may be replicated by waiting until $T_1$ and then investing  one dollar in the stock.  Hence its value must be the same as a zero coupon bond priced at t maturing at $T_1$.

The above holds for any stock dynamics and rate dynamics.